# Error while deploying Hyperledger fabric on openshift

Tags: openshift, hyperledger-fabric

I am using Hyperledger fabric-1.0.1 , openshift v3.4.1.44 , Kubernetes v1.4.0
In my deployment I am having
2 organization, 4 peers , 1 orderer and 2 ca's
I am deploying following YAML on openshift to create PODS and services.

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: ca0
    name: ca0
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: "7054"
      port: 7054
      targetPort: 7054
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: ca0
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: ca1
    name: ca1
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: "8054"
      port: 8054
      targetPort: 7054
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: ca1
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: orderer
    name: orderer
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: "7050"
      port: 7050
      targetPort: 7050
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: orderer
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer01
    name: peer01
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: "7051"
      port: 7051
      targetPort: 7051
    - name: "7053"
      port: 7053
      targetPort: 7053
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: peer01
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer02
    name: peer02
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: "9051"
      port: 9051
      targetPort: 7051
    - name: "9053"
      port: 9053
      targetPort: 7053
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: peer02
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer11
    name: peer11
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: "8051"
      port: 8051
      targetPort: 7051
    - name: "8053"
      port: 8053
      targetPort: 7053
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: peer11
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer12
    name: peer12
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: "10051"
      port: 10051
      targetPort: 7051
    - name: "10053"
      port: 10053
      targetPort: 7053
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: peer12
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: ca0
    name: ca0
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: ca0
      spec:
        containers:
        - args:
          - sh
          - -c
          - fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
            --ca.keyfile /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/PK-KEY
            -b admin:adminpw -d
          env:
          - name: FABRIC_CA_HOME
            value: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
          - name: FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME
            value: ca-org1
          - name: FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
          - name: FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/PK-KEY
          image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.1
          name: ca-peerorg1
          ports:
          - containerPort: 7054
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/hyperledger
            name: ca0-claim0
          - mountPath: /var/fabricdeploy
            name: common-claim
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - name: ca0-claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ca0-pvc
        - name: common-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: fabric-deploy
  status: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: ca0-pvc
    name: ca0-pvc
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 100Mi
  status: {}
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: ca1
    name: ca1
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: ca1
      spec:
        containers:
        - args:
          - sh
          - -c
          - fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
            --ca.keyfile /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/PK-KEY
            -b admin:adminpw -d
          env:
          - name: FABRIC_CA_HOME
            value: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
          - name: FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME
            value: ca-org2
          - name: FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
          - name: FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/PK-KEY
          image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.1
          name: ca-peerorg2
          ports:
          - containerPort: 7054
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/hyperledger
            name: ca1-claim0
          - mountPath: /var/fabricdeploy
            name: common-claim
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - name: ca1-claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ca1-pvc
        - name: common-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: fabric-deploy
  status: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: ca1-pvc
    name: ca1-pvc
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 100Mi
  status: {}
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: orderer
    name: orderer
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: orderer
      spec:
        containers:
        - args:
          - orderer
          env:
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE
            value: /var/fabricdeploy/fabric-samples/first-network/channel-artifacts/genesis.block
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD
            value: file
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS
            value: 0.0.0.0
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR
            value: /var/code/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID
            value: OrdererMSP
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL
            value: debug
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE
            value: /var/code/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY
            value: /var/code/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS
            value: '[/var/code/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt]'
          image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.1 
          name: orderer
          ports:
          - containerPort: 7050
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/fabricdeploy
            name: common-claim
          - mountPath: /var
            name: ordererclaim1
          workingDir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - name: common-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: fabric-deploy
        - name: ordererclaim1
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: orderer-pvc
  status: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: orderer-pvc
    name: orderer-pvc
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 100Mi
  status: {}

- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer01
    name: peer01
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: peer01
      spec:
        containers:
        - args:
          - peer
          - node
          - start
          env:
          - name: CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL
            value: DEBUG
          - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
            value: peer01.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT
            value: peer01.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER
            value: "false"
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_ID
            value: peer0.org1.example.com
          - name: CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID
            value: Org1MSP
          - name: CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt

          - name: CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp

          image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.1
          name: peer01
          ports:
          - containerPort: 7051
          - containerPort: 7053
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var
            name: peer01claim0
          - mountPath: /var/fabricdeploy
            name: common-claim
          workingDir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - name: peer01claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: peer01-pvc
        - name: common-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: fabric-deploy
  status: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer01-pvc
    name: peer01-pvc
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 100Mi
  status: {}

- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer02
    name: peer02
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: peer02
      spec:
        containers:
        - args:
          - peer
          - node
          - start
          env:
          - name: CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL
            value: DEBUG
          - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
            value: peer02.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP
            value: peer02.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER
            value: "false"
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_ID
            value: peer0.org2.example.com
          - name: CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID
            value: Org2MSP
          - name: CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.key
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt

          - name: CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp

          image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.1
          name: peer02
          ports:
          - containerPort: 7051
          - containerPort: 7053
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var
            name: peer02claim0
          - mountPath: /var/fabricdeploy
            name: common-claim
          workingDir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - name: peer02claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: peer02-pvc
        - name: common-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: fabric-deploy
  status: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer02-pvc
    name: peer02-pvc
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 100Mi
  status: {}

- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer11
    name: peer11
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: peer11
      spec:
        containers:
        - args:
          - peer
          - node
          - start
          env:
          - name: CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL
            value: DEBUG
          - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
            value: peer11.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP
            value: peer01.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT
            value: peer11.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER
            value: "false"
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_ID
            value: peer1.org1.example.com
          - name: CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID
            value: Org1MSP
          - name: CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt

          - name: CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp

          image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.1
          name: peer11
          ports:
          - containerPort: 7051
          - containerPort: 7053
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var
            name: peer11claim0
          - mountPath: /var/fabricdeploy
            name: peer11claim1
          workingDir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - name: peer11claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: peer11-pvc
        - name: peer11claim1
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: fabric-deploy
  status: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer11-pvc
    name: peer11-pvc
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 100Mi
  status: {}

- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer12
    name: peer12
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: peer12
      spec:
        containers:
        - args:
          - peer
          - node
          - start
          env:
          - name: CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL
            value: DEBUG
          - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
            value: peer12.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP
            value: peer12.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT
            value: peer12.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER
            value: "false"
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_ID
            value: peer1.org2.example.com
          - name: CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID
            value: Org2MSP
          - name: CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
            value: "false"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls/server.key
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt

          - name: CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
            value: /var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp

          image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.1
          name: peer12
          ports:
          - containerPort: 7051
          - containerPort: 7053
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var
            name: peer12claim0
          - mountPath: /var/fabricdeploy
            name: peer12claim1
          workingDir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - name: peer12claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: peer12-pvc
        - name: peer12claim1
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: fabric-deploy
  status: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: peer12-pvc
    name: peer12-pvc
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 100Mi
  status: {}

kind: List
metadata: {}
```

When I tried to executed steps of script.sh https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/first-network/scripts ([Hyperledger fabric -Building Your First Network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bu)) to build network I am getting error at step installChaincode.

```
    :/var/fabricdeploy/fabric-samples/first-network/scripts$ ./script.sh
    Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test
    Channel name : mychannel
    Creating channel...
    CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
    .
    .
     .
    2017-08-31 13:56:02.520 UTC [main] main -> INFO 021 Exiting.....
    ===================== Channel "mychannel" is created successfully =====================

    Having all peers join the channel...
    CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    .
    .
    .
    2017-08-31 13:56:02.565 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: digest: F98AD2F3EFC2B7B6916C149E819B7F322C29595623D48A90AB14899C0E2DDD51
    2017-08-31 13:56:02.591 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 006 Peer joined the channel!
    2017-08-31 13:56:02.591 UTC [main] main -> INFO 007 Exiting.....
    ===================== PEER0 joined on the channel "mychannel" =====================

    CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    .
    .
    .
    2017-08-31 13:56:04.669 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 006 Peer joined the channel!
    2017-08-31 13:56:04.669 UTC [main] main -> INFO 007 Exiting.....
    ===================== PEER1 joined on the channel "mychannel" =====================

    CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    .
    .
    .

    2017-08-31 13:56:06.760 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 006 Peer joined the channel!
    2017-08-31 13:56:06.760 UTC [main] main -> INFO 007 Exiting.....
    ===================== PEER2 joined on the channel "mychannel" =====================

    CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    .
    .
    .

    2017-08-31 13:56:08.844 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 006 Peer joined the channel!
    2017-08-31 13:56:08.844 UTC [main] main -> INFO 007 Exiting.....
    ===================== PEER3 joined on the channel "mychannel" =====================

    Updating anchor peers for org1...
    CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    .
    .
    .

    2017-08-31 13:56:10.934 UTC [main] main -> INFO 010 Exiting.....
    ===================== Anchor peers for org "Org1MSP" on "mychannel" is updated successfully =====================

    Updating anchor peers for org2...
    CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    .
    .
    .
    2017-08-31 13:56:11.006 UTC [main] main -> INFO 010 Exiting.....
    ===================== Anchor peers for org "Org2MSP" on "mychannel" is updated successfully =====================

    Installing chaincode on org1/peer0...
    CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
    CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
    CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
    CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
    CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/code/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    CORE_PEER_ID=cli
    CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer01.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051
    2017-08-/opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95EBU 001 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.30.217.53:7051: getsockopt: connection refused";
    runtime.sigpanic()peer01.first-network.svc.cluster.local:7051 <nil>}
    fatal er/opt/go/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:12 +0x2ccn
    [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x47 pc=0x7fb7242db259]
    goroutine 20 [syscall, locked to thread]:
    runtime.cgocall(0xb08d50, 0xc4200265f8, 0xc400000000)
    runtime./opt/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:131 +0x110 fp=0xc4200265b0 sp=0xc420026570
    net._C2f??:0 +0x68 fp=0xc4200265f8 sp=0xc4200265b0018d6e0, 0xc42013c158, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    net.cgoL/opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:146 +0x37c fp=0xc420026718 sp=0xc4200265f8
    net.cgoI/opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:198 +0x4d fp=0xc4200267a8 sp=0xc420026718
    runtime./opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086 +0x1 fp=0xc4200267b0 sp=0xc4200267a8
    created /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:208 +0xb4
            /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:434 +0x856
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.Dial(0xc420018092, 0x2b, 0xc420357300, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc420357300, 0x2, 0x4)
    github.c/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:319 +0x960018092, 0x2b, 0xc420357300, 0x4, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    github.c/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm/connection.go:191 +0x2a9b, 0x490001, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc, 0xc420018092, 0x2b)
    github.c/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/peer/peer.go:500 +0xbe018092, 0x2b, 0xc420018092, 0x2b, 0xc4201a5988)
    github.c/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/peer/peer.go:475 +0x4e4201a59c0, 0x0)
    github.c/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common/common.go:114 +0x29 0x0, 0xc4200001a0)
    github.c/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/common.go:240 +0x77a
    github.c/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/install.go:166 +0x5a8 0xd9d943, 0x5)
    github.c/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/install.go:54 +0x54, 0x0, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0)

    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Chaincode installation on remote peer PEER0 has Failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    ========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

Comment: Is this Ubuntu or Red hat / CentOS? what's the processor architecture?

Comment: OS : linux-amd64

Comment: what distribution? ubuntu or red hat?

Comment: DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu ,
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04,DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial 
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"